# Обращение к элементам через псевдоклассы

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, ul

Элементов родительского списка может быть бесконечное множество. Моя задача сделать код универсальным, убрав из html классы и обратиться к элементам через псевдоклассы CSS.

Я добралась до всех, кроме списка `.inner` и его элементов.

Как обратиться только через псевдоклассы к:

```
.inner

.inner li

.inner li:first-child

.inner li:last-child
```

HTML:

```
<section class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <ul class="inner">
                       <li>Адрес</li>
                       <li>Телефон</li>
                   </ul>
               </li>     
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li>Адрес</li>
                        <li>Телефон</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>     
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Считаю нужным предупредить что использование длинных и сложных селекторов это плохая практика, а поддерживать такой код будет крайне сложно.

Если Вас это не останавливает, то:

```
section > ul > ul > ul {
   // .inner
}

section > ul > ul > ul li {
   // .inner li (все, включая вложенные)
}

section > ul > ul > ul > li {
   // .inner li (только прямые наследники)
}


section > ul > ul > ul li:first-child {
   // .inner li:first-child 
}

section > ul > ul > ul li:last-child {
   // .inner li:last-child 
}
```

Без классов или других аттрибутов у элементов Вам не к чему будет "привязаться", а следовательно и не будет возможности как то упростить селекторы типа `section > ul > ul > ul` используя псевдоклассы такие как [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) и ему подобные.

[Справочник по CSS Селекторам](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ) Такая запись через прямых потомков что-то ломает, например, перестаёт работать flex на элементах списка.     "упростить селекторы типа section > ul > ul > ul используя псевдоклассы такие как :nth-of-type и ему подобные." -- буду благодарна, если приведете пример)

Comment: Именно об этом я и написал вначале. CSS это каскад, если Вы хотите переписать уже существующий код и отказаться от классов то Вам придется заново проверить правильно ли происходит наследование.

Comment: _без классов и/или других атрибутов у элементов, относительно вашего примера, этого сделать неполучиться_ имею в виду, какому элементу вы бы присвоили класс и какой nth-child указывали бы? не могу сообразить, как адекватнее это сделать